# JAXBElements generated from wsdl in Mule

Tags: jaxb, wsdl, mule, mule-studio

We have a wsdl that we want to use in Mule studio. We generated the Java classes through the CXF component. There are a lot of elements in the schemas that are like this : 
`<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SortIndex" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>`
In the generated Java classes, we get them as JAXBElement which is not really nice as it is hard to work with those in the DataMapper. I saw that this behavior can be overriden by providing jaxb bindings. However, this is how our wsdl looks now:

```
    <wsdl:portType name="ILegacy">
    <jaxws:bindings
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
            wsdlLocation="src\main\resources\Legacy.wsdl"
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
            xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
            xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
        <enableWrapperStyle>false</enableWrapperStyle>
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/> 
    </jaxws:bindings>
```

However, this doesnt change the generation of JAXBElements. Is there something wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you suing wsdl2java or xjc? or something else?

If you are using CXF wsdl2java or xjc pass in your binding file as a parameter to the command:

bindings123.xjb:

```
 <jaxws:bindings
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
            wsdlLocation="src\main\resources\Legacy.wsdl"
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
            xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
            xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
        <enableWrapperStyle>false</enableWrapperStyle>
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/> 
    </jaxws:bindings>
```

then use -b to pass the bindings file to jaxb:

```
xjc schema1.xsd schema2.xsd schema3.xsd -b bindings123.xjb
```

Comment: Hej Ryan! I have started my post explaining how we generated them: "We have a wsdl that we want to use in Mule studio. We generated the Java classes through the CXF component. " So, we generated the Java classes through Mule studio where there is no such option to run with -b and external jaxws bindings file.